# Select query with NOT LIKE and other conditions not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
SELECT *
FROM products 
WHERE  (
  Model LIKE :productModel  
  AND hidden ='no' 
  AND Model != :productModelopt2 
  AND (Color = :productColor OR Color = '')
  AND (Manufacturer = :productManufacturer OR Manufacturer = '') 
  AND Category != :productCategory AND Category NOT LIKE '%Pre-Owned%'
)
```

This doesn't work as for some reason it still returns Products where the Category field contains Pre-Owned.  All the other conditions are working correct

When I change the NOT LIKE to LIKE it returns the correct items (only items where the conditions are met and the Category field contains Pre-Owned

Can anybody please help me so the NOT LIKE condition is also met.

Comment: Create a fiddle with the one row which causes problems, and the exact SQL you used: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 ... Add that detail to the question.

Comment: @Ria - Can you attach image for the output that you are getting?